# ModelState Error will keep displaying after refresh the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following GET Action method:-

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
             return View(groupRepository.Find(id));
        }
```

I have the following POST Action method:-

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(Group group)
        {

            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    AuditInfo auditinfo = repository.IntiateAudit(2, 2, User.Identity.Name, 2);



                    groupRepository.InsertOrUpdate(group);
                    groupRepository.Save();

                    repository.InsertOrUpdateAudit(auditinfo);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();

                var clientValues = (Group)entry.Entity;

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
                + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                + "the Save button again. Otherwise click the Back to List hyperlink."); }
```

But the problem is that in case the (DbUpdateConcurrencyException) is raised then the ModelState error will keep displaying, after the user refresh the page.

Second problem is that after the refresh the old values will keep displaying, instead of viewing the updated values from the database.

But in case i click on the browser URL and click "Enter" then the error will be removed, and the values will be retrieved from the Database ,unlike  refreshing the page.

Finally the Find method is :-

```
    public Group Find(int id)
            { return context.Groups.Find(id) ;}
```

**::EDIT::**

I have updated my POST EDIT action method to be:-

```
   catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
                var databaseValues = (Group)entry.GetDatabaseValues().ToObject();
               entry.Reload();
                var clientValues = (Group)entry.Entity;

                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The record you attempted to edit "
                + "was modified by another user after you got the original value. The "
                + "edit operation was canceled and the current values in the database "
                + "have been displayed. If you still want to edit this record, click "
                + "the Save button again. Otherwise click the Back to List hyperlink.");
               // department.Timestamp = databaseValues.Timestamp;
                group.timestamp = databaseValues.timestamp;
```

But still after the ModelState error is displayed the old client values will still be displayed , instead of displaying the fresh values from the database ? can you advice on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Reload` to fetch the current values from the database:

```
//...
catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
{
    var entry = ex.Entries.Single();
    entry.Reload();
    //...
}
return View(group);
//...
```

If you click on Refresh in the browser it will repeat to send a POST request. It's like clicking the submit button again. As long as you don't have the current values in the browser form you will hit the same concurrency exception again. Hitting Enter on the Url will send a GET request, so your GET action will be called and the current values loaded and displayed.

Comment: @johnG: The problem is that the form fields in the view are filled by the current model state which is not updated after reloading the `group` entity. Can you try to add `ModelState.Clear()` **before** the  `ModelState.AddModelError(...)` line in the `catch` block and see if that works for you?

Comment: thanks for your help. it worked well after adding the ModelState.Clrea(). but actually i did not understand why it will not work unless i  clear the model state?

Comment: @johnG: If `return View(group)` is called and the form fields are filled MVC checks first if the `ModelState` dictionary contains a value for the form field (which is the case after a POST request). If yes it puts this value into the field. Only if no, the value is taken from `group`. It's a measure to give the user the values back they have really entered. Imagine you have a property of type `int` and the user enters `"a"` into the field. This is invalid and the property will have `0` as value after posting the form. By using ModelState the user gets `"a"` back, otherwise it would be `0`.

Comment: but since i am clearing the ModelState only if the DbUpdateConcurrencyException occured then i am in the right track ?

Comment: @johnG: Yes, I think so. The form fields should be filled like after a  new GET request plus the manually added model error is displayed. Without the concurrency exception you should get normal validation errors.